# Predict Probability Distribution with Neural Network or Monte Carlo

Tags: neural-networks, markov-chain-montecarlo, conv-neural-network

Let's say we would like to predict price of Microsoft Stock. We have historical data and interested in predicting **price distribution** for future time `t+1`, like shown on the image.

We can use classical Neural Network approach to predict the price, but it would be a **single number**, not distribution.

1. Question - **is there a way to make Neural Network to output the price distribution** (CNN for sequences as a Neural Network)?
2. Question - as far as I know it's possible to do such thing with Markov Chain Monte Carlo. You run it a lots of times, collect the outputs, the predictions and then calculate the distribution. **Could Monte Carlo approach be used with Neural Network**, instead of Markov Chain (CNN for sequences as a Neural Network)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

MCMC methods are typically used for sampling from a distribution which otherwise would be very difficult to sample from. They do this by defining a markov chain whose equilibrium distribution is the desired distribution.

Neural networks are general function approximators. You can interpret the output as a probability distribution, in which case they can be used to model complex distributions.

So to answer your questions

1. yes
2. not really sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

1. Neural networks can only really give point estimates, not distributions. Bayesian neural networks can output distributions, so you can take a look into those but are harder to work with.
2. MCMC and deep learning are pretty disparate fields. MCMC uses random sampling to approximate a distribution, whereas deep learning approximates a function through minimizing a cost function. You wouldn't use MCMC to train a neural net, if that's what you're asking.